# How to send logs to papertrail heroku add-on from a job not running on heroku?

Tags: heroku, logging, papertrail-app

I have an application running on Heroku using the papertrail add-on. Everything works perfectly and logs from that app are shown in there. My problem comes when I want to log to the same papertrail account from jobs running in other servers like AWS. In particular, I'm trying to setup a docker container for jobs that are only run in certain occasions (and for some technical limitations they cannot be run in heroku).

I have checking [how to setup the unix loggers to automatically send logs to papertrail](https://www.papertrail.com/solution/tips/how-to-configure-remote-syslog/). My problem is that I do not have a papertrail dns or a port. Heroku only gives a papertrail token.

Any idea how to send logs to papertrail using my add-on credentials from a different unix server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [logspout](https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout) which can route all container logs (from the host) to a different location, for example to papertrail.

You can find a `docker run` example of the website, here below is a `docker-compose` example which is quite convenient when you run multiple containers and want to gather all logs together.

The destination `logs2.papertrailapp.com:55555` is provided by Papertrail in Settings->Log Destinations

```
logspout:
  image: gliderlabs/logspout:latest
  container_name: logspout
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
  command: syslog+tls://logs2.papertrailapp.com:55555
  ports:
    - 8082:80
  networks:
    - my_network
```

Comment: You do not have a Log Destination section in the sections of the Heroku add-on.

Comment: I mean directly in the Papertrail configuration (the idea is to aggregate directly the logs in Papertrail without going via Heroku add-on - for applications hosted somewhere else)